# HTTP Error 405.0 while saving content in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, http, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I wonder why, while saving content in TinyMCE:s editor, I always get the error "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used." Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form method="get">
                <textarea id="mytextarea">This is an implementation of TinyMCE in an Angular application.</textarea>
                <button name="submitbtn"></button>
            </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",       // tillägg av plugins line fick
          "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",                           // Insert, Table och Tools menyer att dyka upp
          "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
          "save", /*HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.*/

          //'codemirror'
        ],
        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code | save'
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards, Attila

Comment: would you submit your form by get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a form can be submitted using the GET method, a form should (in general) be submitted using HTTP POST (not GET). For example:

```
<form method="post" action="URLToSendFileTo.php">
...
</form>
```

(Submitting using GET has limitations in the amount of content you can submit and the form content becomes part of the URL which can be undesired in many situations)

*When using the form tag you need to provide an `action` attribute so the page knows to where it should post the information.*

This page provides more details on the `<form>` tag and its options:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

As a side note ... there are 5 basic HTTP Verbs that you may need to use in your development.  A brief overview of how each are generally used can be found here:

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html